# Url scheme in Facebook feed dialog

Tags: objective-c, xcode, facebook, facebook-graph-api

So I finally got a link in my facebook post using the properties parameters. I thought I could put my url scheme in there. But unfortunately it says it isn't a valid url, which makes sense. So I searched again for another solution. But everyone seems to be talking about fb:// and not their own app url scheme.

So I created this thread, hope somebody can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try using bit.ly (or some other URL shortener).

The last time I tried, bit.ly accepted any URI schema and just did a redirect. I've successfully used this in the past to work around inputs that expected either an HTTP or HTTPS schema.

Additionally, similar logic could be done on your own server if you prefer. Simply share a link to your own server on Facebook, and have your server side script do a 301 to whatever App specific URI you have.

Comment: That's what I thought about doing today. I will try this soon enough. Thanks for replying though.

Comment: I have another problem with the native facebook app now. It doesn't seem like I am able to see the properties links in the app. You know something about this?